# didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo not returning UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I'm using a UIImagePickerController to select a photo and later edit it using TOCropViewController:

```
if (UIImagePickerController.IsSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary))
        {
            var picker = new UIImagePickerController
            {
                SourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary,
                WeakDelegate = this
            };

            PresentViewController(picker, true, () =>
            {
                
            });
        }
```

Most of the times it works correctly, but for some images didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo is not returning UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage.

```
[Export("imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:")]
    private void FinishedPickingMedia(UIImagePickerController picker, NSDictionary dic)
    {
      //Here img is sometimes null, because UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage is not found

        var img = dic.ObjectForKey(new NSString("UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage")) as UIImage;

        picker.DismissViewController(true, () =>
        {
            try
            {
                _cropViewController = new TOCropViewController(TOCropViewCroppingStyle.Default, img)
                {
                    AspectRatioLockEnabled = true,
                    AspectRatioPickerButtonHidden = true,
                    AspectRatioPreset = TOCropViewControllerAspectRatioPreset.Square,
                    Delegate = _croppingDelegate,
                    ResetAspectRatioEnabled = false
                };

                PresentViewController(_cropViewController, true, null);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Crashes.TrackError(ex);
            }
        });
    }
```

So for example when things are ok I'm getting a result such as:

> "UIImagePickerControllerMediaType" = "public.image";

> "UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage" = <UIImage:0x280a3c360 anonymous {820, 512}>;

> "UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL" = assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=4EDD6F79-865E-48C9-AB91-99E58E5F323B&ext=JPG;

> "UIImagePickerControllerImageURL" = file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/8FB0FD8E-98A4-4C28-9687-E33BCE53D460/tmp/2107BB84-ECF3-47E0-9538-B380B29E7BE9.jpeg;

When I'm not getting the UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage the result is:

> "UIImagePickerControllerMediaType" = "public.image";

> "UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL" = assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=567381A3-D0AC-4124-9CCD-C526E0074F83&ext=JPG;

And I don't get a UIImage to edit.

What can cause this behaviour and what can be done to resolve it?

Comment: It's written in C# (using Xamarin). I've added the tag.

Comment: Please show `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`.

Comment: Could you upload a code sample which could reproduce on GitHub for us to test?